# Do I need to setup my own Proxy Address/Server in Ubuntu Server 22.04 to use "sudo apt update"?

Tags: apt, server, updates, proxy

Ubuntu newbie here.

When using the "sudo apt update" command, I receive the following errors below. When searching around, it seems like the resolution is I need to setup a proxy server? (https://linuxiac.com/how-to-use-apt-with-proxy/)

When I setup my Ubuntu Server, I didn't input any info for "proxy server".

**This Ubuntu Server is being setup for at home use / linux training. So I didn't use Ubuntu Desktop. Should I have in this case?**

Errors I get when using "sudo apt update"

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection reused)
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cold not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelase  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRlease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InReease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones usedinstead.
```

My setup: Ubuntu Server 22.04 via Virtual Box

- I setup my Ubuntu Server with a static ip as I will be ssh-ing into the Ubuntu Server from MobaXterm. Which requires me to use Adapter 1: NAT and Adapter 2: Host-only Adapter in Virtual Box to be able to configure Static IP.

enp0s8 is my static ip I setup

````
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea7:4074  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a7:40:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154  bytes 20644 (20.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 193  bytes 18082 (18.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed2:c892  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:d2:c8:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3567  bytes 286366 (286.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3522  bytes 373812 (373.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 532  bytes 47862 (47.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 532  bytes 47862 (47.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    ```
````

Comment: Just to be sure, you _did_ set up a proxy server at `127.0.0.1:8080`? Telling `apt` about a proxy, like in the tutorial you linked, doesn't create the proxy server itself. It basically just tells `apt`, "when you're downloading something, don't go to the internet directly, but try to reach anything through the following intermediary". It looks like that intermediary isn't there or isn't taking any requests for some reason.

Comment: Nope, I haven't setup anything. I didn't input any info in the proxy section when setting up the Ubuntu Server. That's why I'm confused.

Do I need to setup a proxy server?

Comment: To have `apt` (or anything, for that matter) use a proxy server, you need to have a proxy server, correct ;) Whether you set up a proxy server yourself or use one provided to you (by your IT department, your ISP or other), you need to have one. Otherwise, it's a bit like you say "drive _this_ car to the grocery store" without having a car ;) Maybe you want to read up on what a proxy server is and does. Because running a proxy on `localhost`, the same machine the client is one, doesn't seem that useful to me ;)

Comment: Did you look in Settings -> Software & Updates to see if you have any local (Other Software) 3rd party repository enabled that could be causing this?

Comment: I'm only using it for homesetup / linux training. Nothing extraordinary. 


@HenningKockerbeck

To conclude, your saying I need to setup a proxy server in Ubuntu like below?

https://citizix.com/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: @Terrance

I'm on Ubuntu Server, I don't have the GUI :(

Comment: Sorry, use `grep "127.0.0.1" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to see if any of those have that listed.

Comment: @Terrance When running the command you suggested, this is what comes back:

"grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list~: No such file or directory"

Comment: Or try `grep -iR "127.0.0.1" /etc/apt/*`   You might though need to fix your question and title because you make it sound like you want a proxy setup, but then your question shows that you are erroring out with a proxy that you don't want.

Comment: @Terrance When I try the command "grep -iR "127.0.0.1" /etc/apt/*" Nothing comes back.

Thank you for the suggestion. I'm assuming that's what I need based on what I've googled. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You shouldn't need a proxy set, unless you have one between you and the internet.  One other search you can try on that system would be `sudo grep -iRE "localhost|127.0.0.1" /etc/*` since all configuration files should be somewhere in the `/etc/` directory.

Comment: @Terrace I get some results back. There is a character limit so I can't post it all. Is there a line you would like to search for specificly?

Comment: @Terrance

/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
/etc/hosts:127.0.0.1 localhost
/etc/hosts:::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
/etc/lvm/lvm.conf:      #     System IDs beginning localhost are not permitted.
/etc/security/pam_env.conf:# to "localhost" rather than not being set at all
/etc/security/pam_env.conf:#REMOTEHOST  DEFAULT=localhost OVERRIDE=@{PAM_RHOST}
/etc/security/pam_env.conf:#NNTPSERVER  DEFAULT=localhost
/etc/security/access.conf:#+:root:127.0.0.1
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:#X11UseLocalhost yes
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf:#CacheFromLocalhost=no

Comment: @01Tech If you want to practice how to set up a proxy server, you can of course do that. I haven't look at the tutorial you've linked in detail, so I can't say how good or bad it is. For anything else, I would agree with Terrance: So far, you haven't explained why you think you need `apt` to use a proxy in the first place. If there's no reason why `apt` can't (or shouldn't) connect to the internet directly, I wouldn't bother with a proxy (other than for learning purposes, see above).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck

The reason for it I guess is because when I googled my issue, that's what came up to solve the problem. It stated you need a proxy server to get apt updates and I'm just following those instructions.

I don't know if this matters,  but here is my setup:

Ubuntu Server 22.04 via Virtual Box

- I setup my Ubuntu Server with a static ip as I will be ssh-ing into the Ubuntu Server from MobaXterm. Which requires to use Adapter 1: NAT and  Adapter 2: Host-only  Adapter

Check the main comment (I added my network interfaces)

Comment: @Terrance

In the main question at the top, I added some of my setup information and network information if that helps bring some clarification.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck In the main question at the top, I added some of my setup information and network information if that helps bring some clarification.

Comment: @01Tech Typically, you _don't_ need a proxy server to get updates via `apt`. In case your system overall can't (or shouldn't, for example for security reasons) connect to the internet directly, you _can_ tell `apt` about an intermediary. That is a proxy server, which of course needs to exist somewhere, be reachable and so forth. If your system can connect to the internet in general, like for example to ping some website, I don't see a reason why you should need a proxy. And if your system _can't_ reach the internet directly, a proxy running on the server itself couldn't, either ;)

Comment: @01Tech Maybe you want to ask a new question about your original issue (or check whether it has been asked and answered already).

Comment: @01Tech I just saw that you changed the title of your question and with that, basically changed your question ;) I've added an answer to the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's useful to first summarize what a proxy server does. Very often, a system can connect to the internet directly. If that's the case, any program on that system can connect to the internet directly - a web browser, a mail client, `apt` or anything else.

But there are also cases where a system can't or shouldn't directly connect to the internet. That could be because of how the local network is set up, for security reasons, to filter out unwanted content like ads, to ensure compliance to some kind of regulations or for other reasons.

If that's the case, you can use a proxy server. A proxy server is an intermediate that connects to a destination somewhere in the internet instead of you. Say, you want to visit `askubuntu.com` in your web browser. If your system can connect to the internet directly, your browser can just connect to the server(s) `askubuntu.com` is running on:

```
Your system --> askubuntu.com
```

If your system can't or shouldn't connect to the internet directly, you can use a proxy server as an intermediate. A proxy server basically takes your request and sends it to the intended destination:

```
Your system --> Proxy --> askubuntu.com
```

Additionally, a proxy server can check whether the connection is allowed by some kind of company rules, filter out malware and other unwanted content or perform other services.

So, a proxy server is only needed if you can't or shouldn't access the internet directly - that goes for systems as a whole as well as individual programs like `apt` or others. Unless you have a specific reason to have `apt` use a proxy server, you don't need to.

If you *do* want `apt` to use a proxy server for a specific reason, you can do so with the `Aquire` configuration described in the tutorial that you linked. But in this case, obviously the proxy server you want `apt` to use needs to exist, to be reachable and so on.

Comment: I don't want to use a proxy server, I'm just going based off of what I googled around and seen come back as a resolution.

Comment: Ok, let's got the very beginning of the matter: _Why_ do you think you need `apt` to use a proxy server? And I don't mean "because Google told me to" ;) What is the problem you wanted to solve at the very beginning of all this?

Comment: When trying to user "sudo apt update", I get the errors above. I want to be able to user "sudo apt update" without getting the connection errors I got above. I don't know any other reason for needing the proxy server besides what I seen searching my problem. I don't know how else to answer this.

Which is stated here: https://linuxiac.com/how-to-use-apt-with-proxy/

Comment: @01Tech Somehow, either `apt` specifically or your system as a whole tries to connect to `127.0.0.1:8080` for some reason. Please check the following: a) Does the name resolution work? Use `dig` to check what ip address `us.archive.ubuntu.com` resolves to. it shouldn't be `127.0.0.1`. b) Check if either the system as a whole or `apt` specifically already has a proxy configured somehow. For example, can you `ping` some site on the internet? What does `traceroute` for a site on the internet say? If either tries to connect to `127.0.0.1`, then that's the trail you need to follow further.